# Программа не выводит правильный процент P

Tags: c++, c++11, численные-методы

**Задача**: Под какой процент p выдана ссуда величиной S рублей, которая гасится месячными
выплатами величиной m в течение n лет. На вход задачи получаем S,m,n.

**Формула нахождения m**: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос и моё решение**: Программа в целом ничего не выводит при попытке сравнения m и copy. При попытке решения для S = 1000000, m = 14749, n = 10 , вместо 12, программа ничего не выводит. Подскажите, в чём ошибка или предложите альтернативное решение задачки.

**Моё решение**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    double S, m, n;
    double r, copy;
    double p;
    cin >> S >> m >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i ++){
        p = i;
        r = p/100;
        copy = (n * r * pow((1 + r), n)) / (12 * (pow(1 + r, n) - 1));
        if (copy == m){
            cout << p;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Да просто *точного* решения не будет практически никогда... Особенно если вы еще и на S помножить забыли...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вся проблема в точности вычислений. На 12 шаге в `copy` получается `14748.7`, а не ваше `14749`. Выхода три:

1. Округлять при сравнении

```
if(round(copy) == m){
    cout << p;
    break;
};
```

2. Сравнивать с пометкой на ошибку (aka epsilon).
   epsilon вам нужно будет подобрать самим, в зависимости от необходимой точности.

```
if(abs(copy-m) < epsilon){
    cout << p;
    break;
};
```

3. Решать аналитически, а не итеративно, хотя, надо сказать, и тут тоже будут погрешности.

P.S.
спасибо [Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1449454/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-p/1449465?noredirect=1#comment2588317_1449465): вместо `(S * r * pow((1 + r), n))` у вас почему-то `(n * r * pow((1 + r), n))`

Comment: Да ТС еще и на S забыл умножить :)

Answer (score 2):

Тут можно получить более точное значение `r` одним из численных методов, например, простых итераций:

```
double S = 1000000, m = 14749, n = 10;

double r = 0.5, old = 0, epsilon = 1e-8; // Точность ваычисления

for(;abs(r - old) > epsilon;)
{
    old = r;
    r = 12*m/S*(1 - 1/pow(1+old,n));
}

cout << r*100 << endl;
```

См. https://ideone.com/c6bMSq